# Adding layer mask on CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

**What I'm trying to do:**

Apply a mask to a UIView using an [UIView] within a UICollectionViewCell.

**Problem I'm having:**

Cells that are not in view at the initial state of the UICollectionView do not apply the mask and thus shows a blank Cell.

[image: cells that apply the mask correctly and some cells that don't]

The green cells are in view when the collectionview loads, the red cells are not in view (outside of the screen). You don't see the red cells until you scroll down. Once you pass the red cells when scrolling down and scroll back to the red cells then the mask is applied.

**Code I use to set the mask**

```
 [![what I'd like to see][1]][1]   /**
 Apply given views as masks

 - Parameter views: Views to apply as mask.

 ## Note: The view calling this function must have all the views in the given array as subviews.
 */
func setMaskingViews(_ views:[UIView], with maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()){
    maskLayer.name = "animatedGradientLayer"

    /* Remove any excess layers */
    layer.sublayers?.removeAll(where: { layer -> Bool in
        layer.name == "animatedGradientLayer"
    })

    let mutablePath = CGMutablePath()

    /* Append path for each subview */
    views.forEach { (view) in
        guard self.subviews.contains(view) else{
            fatalError("View:\(view) is not a subView of \(self). Therefore, it cannot be a masking view.")
        }

        view.alpha = 0

        /* Check if ellipse */
        if view.layer.cornerRadius == view.frame.size.height / 2, view.layer.masksToBounds{
            /* Ellipse */
            mutablePath.addEllipse(in: view.frame)
        }else{
            /* Rect */
            mutablePath.addRect(view.frame)
        }
    }

    /* Create layer */
    maskLayer.path = mutablePath

    /* Apply layer as a mask */
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

This method is called in layoutSubviews() in my CollectionViewCell. I also call this method from collectionView(cellForItemAt:) which makes it partially work. The mask appears *only* after the cell has been reused (i.e. the cell is outside of the initial view, I scroll down and past the cell so that it goes out of view, then I scroll back up so that the cell becomes into view).

Just to add, I don't use Storyboards.

Comment: Share the target and current output in screenshot.

Comment: @nitin.agam I have added an image to make it visually easier to understand.